# Flex Bubblechart problem with maxradius

Tags: flex4, charts, bubble-chart

Using Flash builder to create a Flex4 project and the minradius amd maxradius properties have no effect on size of bubbles. Sample data from a larger set is shown below

```
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
 import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
 [Bindable]
        public var myAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {fieldA:1, fieldB:1, qty:13},
            {fieldA:3, fieldB:4, qty:5},
            {fieldA:8, fieldB:31,qty:1}

        ]);

 ]]></mx:Script>
 <mx:BubbleChart 
                id="bubblechart1" 
                 dataProvider="{myAC}">
    <mx:series>
        <mx:BubbleSeries displayName="Series 1"
                         yField="fieldA"
                         xField="fieldB" 
                         radiusField="qty" 
                         minRadius ="1"
                         maxRadius ="2"/>
    </mx:series>
</mx:BubbleChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try minRadius 10 and maxRadius 20. Radius of a bubble is greater than minRadius and is less than maxRadius. On a screen you might see no difference between 1.25 and 1.5 .

Comment: What I am currently seeing with min and max radius set close together is a much greater disparity than I would expect. It is as if there is no account taken of the properties. Using your suggestion has absolutley no impact on what the graph looks like

Comment: I would not mind so much but as I mentioned this is just a sample and there are more  datapoints  with values like fieldA:1, fieldB: qty:9 where the large size of circles just overlap